# 2 different tables with relation to same table in SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

First off I am using LinqToSQL and a data context within my app to query and update a database. My app is a Windows Phone 7 app.

Ok lets say I have 3 tables with columns like so

- **Table A** - `Id, Name, Description`
- **Table B** - `Id, Count, Cost`
- **Table C** - `Id, Name, Description, Type`
- I want to have a relationship between Table A and B which will be one to many (many Table B's to 1 Table A)
- I want to have a relationship between Table C and B which will be one to many (many Table B's to 1 Table C)

So I add extra columns to use for the relationships so now my 3 tables look like this.

- **Table A** - `Id, Name, Description`
- **Table B** - `Id, Count, Cost, TableA_Id, TableC_Id`
- **Table C** - `Id, Name, Description, Type`

I tried setting the above up but Table B will have 2 constraints and if I do something like this in code

```
TableA Ta = new TableA();
Ta.Name = "NA";
Ta.Description = "NA";
Ta.TableB.Add( new TableB()
               {
                 Count = 1,
                 Cost = 100
               });

App.MyDataContext.Database.TableA.InsertOnSubmit(Ta);
App.MyDataContext.Database.SubmitChanges();
```

I get an error like this

> *A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary
>   key value does not exist. [ Foreign key constraint name =
>   FK_TableC_TableB ]*

Now I think I understand why I have the error but I'm asking is there a way to set this setup up so I can achieve the same result without the error. I have used SQL and SQL Server CE a little but this is the first time I tried relationships in this way.

EDIT:
Just for clarification, TableA can contain several TableB. TableC can also contain several TableB

Comment: I don't know enough about the C# framework, but the error's actually pretty clear - you haven't created any data for it to connect `TableB` to `TableC`.  This may just require you to create an instance of `TableC`, and add the existing instance of `TableB` to it (and persist it to the database, along with `TableA`, _before_ calling `SubmitChanges()`).

Comment: Yes that is why there is an error but I want to set this up so I don't have to create the instance of TableC. I know the easiest way would be to create a new Table called TableD which is exactly the same as TableB and then link TableA to TableB and TableC to TableD but then I'm creating 2 table with the same structure, isn't that pointless? or its it in fact then only way to do it?

Comment: If you don't want a record in `TableC`, you're going to have change the FK constraint to be nullable in `TableB`